# SVG image and pattern missing when drawn to canvas or used as image source

Tags: javascript, image, url, svg, canvas

I use SVG to apply filters and patterns to images (need it for printing). My issue is that when I draw the svg to canvas in order to save it as jpeg, the linked image and pattern doesn't show on canvas.

From what I have observed, if I convert the image URL to base64 (for "embedding" it into the SVG) the image shows up on canvas, but I can't do the same thing to the fill property (`fill="url(#dots)"`).

I wonder, is there a way to "rasterize" the svg before I load it into the canvas, or how could I get linked properties to show up on canvas?

this is how svg looks in the browser:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 340 415" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="dots" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <image xlink:href="/data/img/patterns/dots.jpg"  x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
</pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#dots)"></rect>
  <image xlink:href="blob:http://localhost:8081/a80eac2b-722b-4596-99b1-38d2646761f6" id="image" x="4mm" y="4mm" width="82mm" height="82mm" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" filter="url(#walden)"></image>
  <text id="note" x="4.5cm" y="10.2cm" text-anchor="middle" font-size="30px" font-family="Pacifico"><!---->Hello World!<!----></text>
</svg>
```

My code for saving the svg to file:

```
export(){
      var svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('svg');
      var xml = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
      var svg64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(xml);
      var viewbox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox');

      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var width = viewbox.split(' ')[2],
          height = viewbox.split(' ')[3],
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // clear canvas

      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        canvas.toBlob((b)=>{
          that.upload(b);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(img); //for visualising the results
      };

      img.src = svg64;
    }
```

rezults (top: svg, bottom: canvas render)

[image]

Comment: What pattern? You've not shown us the parts that are not working. Is it dots or lines_1 that's the problem? If so what do they point to?

Comment: @RobertLongson, sorry, added the missing pattern definition (see the updated question).

Comment: blob URLs are *(IMM unfortunately)* treated as external resources for documents loaded inside a `<img>`. So they won't be loaded. You need to convert it to a base64 dataURI. (`<image xlink:href="data:image/...`)

Comment: @Kaiido, IMM? I guess converting objectURL to blob gonna give me some headache, I couldn't find a better alternative than using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: "IMM"=>"In My Mind". If you have the Blob, then `f = new FileReader(); f.onload = e => handleDataURI(f.result); f.readAsDataURL(blob);` But depending on where you got it, there might other solutions.

Comment: @Kaiido, hehe. Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried FileReader but that gives me a 16 bit "file" only, representing the DomString, anyway I think I got a solution.

Comment: It is the Blob that you should pass to the FileReader's readAsDataURL, i.e the object you passed to `URL.createObjectURL()` in order to get your blobURL. And it's its `.result` that you want, when it's `onload` event will have fired.

Comment: My case its a bit more complicated, when viewing the image I don't have access to the original Blob any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found for the same problem is to include the patterns inside the svg in base64 encoding:

```
<pattern  id="pat01" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...CC " style="opacity:1;stop-opacity:1" /></pattern>
...
<circle cx="23" cy="153" r="18" style="opacity:1;fill:url(#pat01);fill-opacity:1;stop-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit: 10;"></circle>
```